# Idiom/phrase that means "a point in someone's favor"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm sure there's an idiom/phrase that means that. I thought of *plus one* but found out it means a person who goes with you to an event.

What's the correct idiom/phrase? Example sentence:

> She smiled at my joke. Yes, __.

Comment: More context would be useful. -- P.S. You smile *at* a joke.

Comment: 'Plus one' *can* mean a person who goes with you to an event, but I think it is context driven and, used here, would be understood to mean 'yes, a point in my favour'. If you wish to avoid 'plus one' perhaps 'score one to me' would suit. I've certainly used it in that kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If the person saying “Yes, ___” is the same person who said the first line (or someone sympathetic with/rooting for the speaker of the first line), then the blank could be filled with (and I’d use an exclamation point after “Yes”):

> “Yes! Score/That’s/[Count one for the home
>   team](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=count%20one%20for%20the%20home%20team)”

Please note that *Urban Dictionary* uses “Count” to introduce the expression, but I’m more familiar with the phrase being started with [“**Score** …”(400 or so hits on  *Google Books*)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22score+one+for+the+home+team%22) or sometimes [“**That’s** … ” (10 or so)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22that%27s+one+for+the+home+team%22).
  Regardless, I agree with their definition:

> **count/[score/that’s] one for the home team**
>
> An expression used to signify something good has happened, or can be
>   used to express congratulations. Its antonym is count one for the away
>   team.

(*Urban Dictionary* also lists the expression’s antonym using “the away team,” whereas I would use “the visiting team,” “the other team,” or simply “the visitors” in contexts where the speaker wants to express disappointment, for example if she DID NOT smile at the joke:
 “Yes, score one for the visitors.”)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ***"Touché"***

From Google:

> used as an acknowledgment during a discussion of a good or clever point made at one's expense by another person.

Comment: Touché applies to a counter point (it's from fencing, after all). The key part of the Google definition you cite, which does *not* apply to this question, is **at one's expense**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, that's ***earning a brownie point*** (typically used in plural as *brownie point**s***).

> She smiled at my joke. Yes, *a brownie point earned*.

TFD (idioms):

> **[earn/get brownie points](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/earn+brownie+points)**  (*informal*)
>   to get praise or approval for something you have done
>
> I thought I might get some
>   brownie points by helping to organize the party.